# How to simply host a webpage with Jetty?

Tags: windows, jetty, java

*How* can I host a single "index.html" through *Jetty*?

My idea is to put a webpage that calls an application with JNLP

I really don't know how to serve the page at the first place!
(**or if it is possible** through Jetty)

thanks!

Comment: Have you read http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Develop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at your Jetty home directory structure.
Something like '[YourJettyHome/]webapps/root/index.html', which is the index.html file provided by your Jetty distribution.